# A one to one function from the power set of the naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd like to know if there is an injective function from $P(N)$ (the power set of the natural numbers) to the set of all of the subsets of $P(N)$ which contain the number 5 in them.

In the second part of the question I'm asked to do the same thing, only that now instead of the naturals I'm given a set that its cardinality is $\aleph_0$ and instead of 5, I'm given an element $a$ that belongs to the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do it would be to map any set $A$ to the set $\{5\} \cup (A+6)$.

If the naturals $N$ are replaced by some set $X$ of the same cardinality, fix a bijection $\phi:X \to N$. Under this bijection, your $a\in X$ corresponds to some natural number $\phi(a) \in N$. Then you can map any subset $A$ of $X$ to the subset $\phi^{-1}(\{\phi(a)\} \cup (\phi(A) + \phi(a)))$, which always contains $\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)) = a$.

Comment: Hello Alex! And thank you for your answer! The second part of the question is asking me to do the same thing, only that now we're not talking about the naturals but another a set that its cardinality is א0 and instead of 5, I'm given an element 'a' that belongs to the set..since I do not know what is the set that's metioned in the question I struggle with finding a new asnwer :(

Comment: @Lola You can use a bijection from your set to the natural numbers to identify $a$ with some number, and apply the same argument as the one given here. If you edit your original question to include the second question I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited it as asked:)

Comment: @Lola You mean aleph 0, i.e. the cardinality of the natural numbers, correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed (how should I write it next time?)

Comment: @Lola You can write $\aleph_0$ (see the MathJax documentation for formatting on this site).

Comment: Hey Alex! Thank you again and sorry for bothering again haha..but I'm struggling with proving that the function is injective..How should I do it?

Comment: Never mind! Solved it =) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Define $P$ to be the power set of $\Bbb{N}$, and define $P_5 = \{A\in P\,\vert\,5\in A\}$. Further, define $P'$ to be the power set of $\Bbb{N} -\{5\}$.

Now define $\phi:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}-\{5\}$ so that for $n<5, \phi(n) = n$, and for $n\geq 5, \phi(n)=n+1$. Then $\phi$ is a bijection. Further, $\phi$ induces a bijection $\Phi : P\to P'$ given by

$$\Phi(A) = \{\phi(a) \,\vert \, a\in A\}$$

Next, there is an injection $\Psi: P'\to P_5$ given by $\Psi(A) = A\cup \{5\}$. Then $\Psi\circ \Phi$ is an injection from $P$ to $P_5$.

If you want a bijection, note that $\Psi$ only failed to be a bijection because $\emptyset$ is not in its image. The function can be easily modified to fix this.